# R Shiny: Changing location of image src from www

Tags: r, shiny

I have quite a few images among a few different apps and I would like to store them in one central location.

Current, only images stored in the nested `www` directory of a shiny app seem to work when sourcing images:

```
tags$img(src="img123.img") #Image stored in ./www/plant123.img
```

I would like to query these images from another location, say:

`/opt/images_central`

I have tried using `addResourcePath`, but I have not had success in getting the images to render:

```
addResourcePath("www", "/opt/images_central")
```

Any ideas on how to avoid storing images in the nested www directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while of trying to figure this out, I got it to work.

```
addResourcePath("images", "/opt/images_central")
```

And then I call the images using the following path:

```
images/myimage.jpg
```

I was using: `/images/myimage.jpg` but that does not work.

Comment: im trying to use an image inside `dashboardUser` but I cant get your approach to work. is your final call something like: `dashboardUser(
      name = "x", 
      src = "images/myimage.jpg")`?

Comment: ah i worked it out, for anyone else with this problem "images" is not a folder, so `addResourcePath("not_a_folder_name", "/opt/images_central")` and then call `src = "/not_a_folder_name/myimage.jpg"`